# Где проходит граница между хорошей и плохой погодой?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов, смысл

Где в русском языковом сознании проходит граница между хорошей и плохой погодой? Например, к какой погоде вы отнесёте следующие явления:

- нестерпимая жара;
- лёгкий морозец;
- приятный ветерок;
- грибной дождь;
- лёгкая дымка;
- влажная жара;
- морозный солнечный день?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Хорошая/плохая погода - состояние атмосферы, при котором приятно/неприятно находиться на свежем воздухе.

•нестерпимая жара - ясно, что плохая погода, раз "нестерпимая".

•лёгкий морозец - хорошая погода. Человеку, живущему в климатических зонах, относящихся к России, морозец приятен.

•приятный ветерок - раз "приятный", значит хорошая погода.

•грибной дождь - мелкий, моросящий, дробный дождь из низких туч, идущий в грибную пору при свете солнца ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8C)). 
Хотя грибной дождь и поэтизируют, среднестатистический россиянин не станет гулять под дождем. Значит, плохая погода.

•лёгкая дымка - нейтральное явление, не определяет, хороша ли погода;

•влажная жара - слово "жара" имеет отрицательную коннотацию, значит плохая погода.

•морозный солнечный день - умеренный мороз для россиянина - хорошо, солнце - хорошо. Хорошая погода.

Дополнение (в ответ на критику в комментариях)

Когда произносят "плохая погода", в моем сознании это ассоциируется с дождем и ветром, а не с нестерпимой жарой и лютым морозом. В этом я согласен с критикой. Но не наоборот. Если меня спрашивают, считаю ли я нестерпимую жару плохой погодой, то мой ответ: да, считаю.

Вот навскидку несколько примеров из Сети (в данном случае это аргумент, ведь речь идет о восприятии среднего россиянина). Авторы, так же как и я, считают жару плохой погодой:

*Начнём:сегодня утром моё настроение было не очень из-за Нолика и Фаера,была плохая погода,жара,днём я помогла Дим Димычу* ([Блог Симки](https://ok.ru/zdesyaimoi/topic/64190700254607))

*Полгода плохая погода: то аномальная жара, то беспросветные ливни* ([Облгазета](https://www.oblgazeta.ru/society/24748/))

*Плохая погода (снег, дождь, жара и т. д.) не является основанием для отмены тренировки.* ([Rugby Club](http://rugby-forum.ru/event/trenirovka-v-miit-vt/))

Comment: Отличный ответ. Вот только мне кажется, что понятия хорошая/плохая погода не коррелируют напрямую со степенью комфорта. Так, например, у меня язык не повернётся назвать *жару* плохой погодой. Это просто жара. Тоже самое и про *лютый мороз*. А плохая погода в моём сознании связана именно с осадками и ветром.

Comment: У меня тоже выражение "плохая погода" ассоциируется исключительно с осадками и ветром; иногда это пасмурный день.  Остальное - погода, неблагоприятная для отдельных видов времяпровождения. "Влажная жара" - это и вовсе локальная особенность климата.

Comment: Быстро нашел в Интернете несколько примеров, подтверждаящих мою позицию (в данном случае это аргумент, ведь речь идет о восприятии среднего россиянина):

Comment: Начнём:сегодня утром моё настроение было не очень из-за Нолика и Фаера,была плохая погода,жара,
https://ok.ru/zdesyaimoi/topic/64190700254607

Полгода плохая погода: то аномальная жара, то беспросветные ливни
https://www.oblgazeta.ru/society/24748/


Плохая погода (снег, дождь, жара и т. д.) не является основанием для отмены тренировки.
http://rugby-forum.ru/event/trenirovka-v-miit-vt/

Comment: @Alex_ander Влажная жара - это когда влажно и жарко. Это погода (состояние атмосферы в данный момент).  Есть такие места, где  сегодня ветер с моря - влажно и жарко, а завтра ветер из пустыни - сухо и еще более жарко.

Comment: Плохая погода - когда водка не пьётся (закипает, испаряется при низком давлении или замерзает). Всё остальное - нормальная погода.

Comment: Влажная жара — худший вариант погоды для подавляющего большинства людей. А для многих это ещё и риск для здоровья. И способов спастись от такой погоды меньше всего. (Плюсую ответ.)